# Is this example considered liquifying a gas under pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, temperature, vapor-pressure, gas-phase-chemistry

In my work place, we have a drum that has propene inside at a pressure of around 2,5 bar and at a temperature of around -15ºc and the boil-off of that drum is aspirate by a compressor and is compressed to a pressure around 11 bar to 15 bar and a temperature of around 65ºc to 75ºc. After the compressor the high pressure gas goes to a ventilator, and the gas is cooled down with the ouside air at ambient temperature and that makes the gas to cool down and to change to a liquid at high pressure. After this the liquid is stored at another drum.

My question: is this consider liquifying a gas under pressure?

Note: is not for school purposes.

Comment: Yes. It is a process to liquefy a gas under pressure.

Comment: @Maurice are there other ways to liquefy a gas by applying pressure?

Answer (score 1):

As already noted by Maurice, yes you did liquify a gas under pressure.  In fact, the scope of application is so wide that this is equally known as [Linde cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampson-Linde_cycle).  It is highly possible that you have such an engine at home, either as fridge, or freezer *to cool stuff*, or as [heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump) to *warm* a home.

Regarding propane: equally yes.  After banning Freon and other CFWs, [ammonia](https://www.hunker.com/13409929/how-does-an-ammonia-refrigeration-system-work) (especially industry-scale, e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peVAaLIJJ6c)), propane (more for domestic appliances like [fridges](https://uniqueappliances.com/category/propane-fridges/)) is one of the often seen heat carriers.

The limits regarding how much heat may be shuttled between the warm and the cold side depends on pressure and temperature accessible, formally called the [Carnot cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle):

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle))